# Parsing configure file with same section name in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, configparser

I try to parse file like:

```
[account]
User = first

[account]
User = second
```

I use ConfigParser in Python, but when i read file:

```
Config = configparser.ConfigParser()
Config.read(file)
print (Config.sections())
```

I have error:

```
While reading from ... : section 'account' already exists
```

How can i parse this file? Are any another library? (prefer for python3)

Comment: Do you have control over the config file format?  If yes, change it to something `configparser` likes better.

Comment: I would suggest you write your own parser for it.

Comment: A simple pre-processor would do. But a perfect answer has been given below by alexis.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

If what you want is to simply merge identically named sections (latest one wins), simply pass the `strict=False` option to the constructor (added in Python 3.2). 
You effectively get `dict.update()` behavior as the duplicate sections are merged in.

```
Config = configparser.ConfigParser(strict=False)
```

However, it's clear from the OP's sample data that identically named sections need to be kept separate, to avoid loss of data. `ConfigParser` stores the sections it reads in a dictionary, so it can't handle multiple sections with the same name. Fortunately the constructor accepts a `dict_type` argument that allows you to specify a different dictionary-like object. You can use that to support identically named sections. Here's a crude solution that mangles the section names by appending a unique number whenever a section name has been seen before.

```
from collections import OrderedDict

class multidict(OrderedDict):
    _unique = 0   # class variable

    def __setitem__(self, key, val):
        if isinstance(val, dict):
            self._unique += 1
            key += str(self._unique)
        OrderedDict.__setitem__(self, key, val)

Config = configparser.ConfigParser(defaults=None, dict_type=multidict, strict=False)
```

With a little work you should be able to construct a cleaner solution.

Comment: A pretty neat implementation of this data structure is Armin Ronacher's [`MultiDict`](https://werkzeug.palletsprojects.com/en/0.15.x/datastructures/#werkzeug.datastructures.MultiDict).

Comment: That's a nice interface, I agree. It should work with `configparser` (I haven't tried it), but it would require installing all of flask/Werkzeug as a dependency just to get the MultiDict class.

Comment: Does not work for me. Reading works, but accessing sections by Config['SectionName'] does not work anymore, even if Config.sections() shows the section name. Using Python 3.8

Comment: @OrsirisdeJong a possible workaround is not to override the dict, but do search replace before loading cfg file content to ConfigParser. then you will not have any side effects

Comment: @alexis After using above script, I am again trying to rename my section names as previous ones by removing the appended unique number but it is throwing me Error-- configparser.DuplicateSectionError:

Comment: I don't follow: This code is a solution that avoids creating duplicate names, so that the data can be read in. Then you try to create duplicate names anyway, `configparser` notices and throws an error, and you ask why? It's because you are not supposed to have duplicates in this data model.

Comment: @alexis will you please have a look to my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75520008/need-to-modify-darknet-yolov4-config-cfg-file-but-configparser-configparser-th

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, the format of the provided ini file is not correct according standards. A section's name must be unique in the document.

If you can change the file-format (I already read that you cannot, but for completeness...), then a solution like this would be appropriate:

```
[accounts]
keys= account1, account2

[account1]
User = first

[account2]
User = second
```

If you really can't alternate the file's format, then I fear that your only option is to parse manually the configuration file.

Answer (score 0):

"
If you're deviating from an RFC standard and creating your own config format, you're going to have to write your own parser." This http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1110829 worked for me.  I made a couple of small changes.  ** formatting did not come out correctly when posted

```
def configToDict(file):
# open the file
file = open('settings.cfg')

# create an empty dict
sections = {}

for line in file.readlines():
    # get rid of the newline
    line = line[:-1]
    try:
        # this will break if you have whitespace on the "blank" lines
        if line:
            # skip comment lines
            if line[0] == '#': next
            # this assumes everything starts on the first column
            if line[0] == '[':
                # strip the brackets
                section = line[1:-1]
                # create a new section if it doesn't already exist
                if not sections.has_key(section):
                    sections[section] = {}
            else:
                # split on first the equal sign
                (key, val) = line.split('=', 1)
                # create the attribute as a list if it doesn't
                # exist under the current section, this will
                # break if there's no section set yet
                if not sections[section].has_key(key):
                    sections[section][key] = []
                # append the new value to the list
                sections[section][key].append(val)
    except Exception as e:
        print str(e) + "line:" +line
return sections
```

Answer (score 0):

On the latest python there is an option that may do what you want :
`ConfigParser(strict=True)`

Cf : https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html#configparser.ConfigParser

Comment: Nope, it doesn't-- at least it doesn't do what the OP was after, and accepted. `strict=True` is the default. Setting it to `False` permits multiple sections with the same name, but simply merges their options.