# Configparser in Python does't return all sections with the same name

Tags: python, configparser

## My ini file:

```
[1]

[4]

[5]

[6]

[9]

[1]

[1]
```

## My python Script

```
import configparser
config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.readfp(open('inifile.ini'))
print config.sections()

>>> ['1', '4', '5', '6', '9'] #where are two more '1' ?
```

How to get all actual values ? Configparser must be used.

Comment: Configparser does not support multiple sections of the same name, see a workaround here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/9876059/1781026

Answer (score 1):

In ConfigParser, sections are unique. It stores the sections in `map()`. Hence they should be unique.

As per the [ConfigParser document](https://docs.python.org/2/library/configparser.html#module-ConfigParser):

> The ConfigParser class implements a basic configuration file parser language which provides a structure similar to what you would find on Microsoft Windows **INI files**.

As per the [INI Files wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INI_file#Duplicate_names):

> In some implementations, duplicate sections simply merge their properties together, as if they occurred contiguously. Others may abort, or ignore some aspect of the INI file.

Answer (score 0):

Your conf file should be defined with both section name and section value.
ini file:

```
[database]
host = www.examle.com
port = 1234
```

And try to read value with get method:

```
import configparser
config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.readfp(open('inifile.ini'))

host = config.get('database', 'host')
port = config.getint('database', 'port')
```